# GPS tracking data integration with drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal

I'm developing a drupal website to get the real time data from several GPS devices installed in vehicles.

Each vehicle is associated to a gps device, so the content-type "vehicle" has several properties such as latitude, longitude, status of the device, etc.

The devices send the location information every 5 seconds to the drupal database (but to custom tables) via an api.

There is a lot of data constantly being send so I need to find the most performant way to show it to the user.

As I see it I have 2 options:

1) Update the node for the gps each time the Api recieves the tracking data.

2) Update the node for the gps only when the user is about to see it, implementing a hook for the view, gathering the nodes wich are about to be asked for and updating them before the query is proccessed.

Option n. 1 seems to require a lot of resources but the advantage is that the user get the information quickly.

Option n. 2 may take time to the user, each user is going to be asking for at least 50 gps devices status in each query.

What do you think the best option is?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why are you using Drupal at all? If you are using it just for storing those values  and in custom tables maybe pure PHP is better solution?

Comment: The storing of the values is done by pure php, the administration of the gps boxes is done by drupal. Thats why I need to link both enviroments.

Answer (score 0):

I would expose the custom table in your database to views so that you dont need to duplicate data. To do this in a custom module you need to use [hook_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7)
or you could have a look at the [Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) module